# asymptotic p values of standard normal distributed ? how to calculate them?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, p-value, asymptotics

I do have an estimator which have an asymptotic standard normal distribution under the null hypothesis .How to calculate the asymptotic p values ?

Answer (score 2):

You calculate it from the asymptotic normal distribution.

You know that your estimator has some distribution (asymptotically). You want to know the (asymptotic) p-value.

So just do the integration of the Gaussian or `pnorm` in R (or whatever the command is in your software of choice).

Comment: I use R but i do not know what to put inside this pnorm

Comment: Do you know how to do a z-test in R?

Comment: @ I have forgotten it

Comment: The R code is `pnorm(z)`, where `z` is your calculated test statistic. You'll sometimes have to do `1-pnorm(z)`, and sometimes you'll have to double that calculated value, depending on the specifics of the problem. There are countless resources for this. I like JBStatistics on YouTube.